# How to insert HTML tags into JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to insert HTML code within JavaScript. See the following code as an example.

```
  function myFunction2(x1,x2) {
                 var length = arguments.length;
                 for (var x=0; x<length ; x++)
                 {
                    <h1>arguments[x]</h1>
                 }
}
```

Is this possible? If not, can you suggest an alternative method to do the same work?

Comment: `<h>` isn't an HTML tag and JavaScript isn't HTML, so what you are asking doesn't make any sense. If you want to use JavaScript to add content to an HTML document, then go and read a JavaScript DOM tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Quentin . is it possible to add HTML tag withing javascript. How can i do that?..  here i need to show each arguement as HTML header..

Comment: Seriously, go and read a JavaScript DOM tutorial.

Comment: @TheArkenstone There's a new start-up company called Google that can actually search the interwebs for you and give you an answer to this and find you a JavaScript DOM tutorial...it isn't a very big or well known company but, give them a shot?

Comment: sarcasm @racecarjonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the html `'<b>'+variable+'</b>'` Like this.

Example below.

```js
function myFunction2(x1,x2) {
 var results='';
    var length = arguments.length;
    for (var x=0; x<length ; x++){
      // Close html tag in either ' or " to include array or variables use +
      // '<p>'+MyVariable+'</p>' 
      results+='<h1>'+arguments[x]+'</h1>';
      
    }
  //Target an element you want to use to display your results
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML=results;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">Insert h1 tags here...</div>
<button onclick="myFunction2('Argument One','Argument Two');">Call Function</button>
```

You can find many javascript DOM references online. Not my favorite but [This one](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) will give you plenty of examples to learn from.

Comment: I really expected these kind of answer.. Thank you sir